How to add DynamicJasper report to Jasper Report as sub-report Dynamically
I’m working with a Jasper report in JRXML format, let's say it's mainReport.jrxml. This mainReport contains various fields such as text fields, subreport areas, etc. I’ve add another a subreport in the following manner:
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["subReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

In mainReport.jasper, I aim to include tables with an unpredictable number of columns. If the number of columns were known, I could simply utilize JasperSoft’s built-in table. However, due to the unknown number of columns, I’ve opted to use the Dynamic Jasper library. Following a this suggestion, I’ve successfully created a dynamic Jasper report. Now, my goal is to integrate this Dynamic Jasper report into my mainReport. I attempted to pass this dynamic Jasper report to mainReport as a parameter, but encountered an error. Can anyone provide guidance on how to incorporate a dynamic Jasper report into mainReport?
Here is my JRXML for mainReport
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ncPareto" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3a2d19d1-8c22-4eb3-a2d0-8ddff71bdb55">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <style name="BoldFont" isBold="true"/>
    <parameter name="anotherSubreportDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="companyLogo" class="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"/>
    <parameter name="dynamiJasperReport" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <parameter name="dynamiJasperReportData" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <group name="ReportContents" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="24">
                <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="c8d669fb-85eb-42d5-8b00-b02e2bcd8e26">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{anotherSubreportDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["anotherSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="275" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm">
                <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="130" height="18" uuid="08f30fa9-efb3-4215-bfc9-e7a82c503f5c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="551" height="81" uuid="565dabb7-52e2-4462-9653-c70ae0fef6b9"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyLogo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="255" width="555" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="243c105e-4ccc-4e8b-952b-5cef05cbf648">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{dynamiJasperReportData})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{dynamiJasperReport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>


Here dynamiJasperReport is Dynamic Jasper report that was created using Dynamic Jasper Library. And dynamiJasperReportData holds the data for dynami Jasper Report.
Here is how we are filling mainReport
        Pair<JasperReport, Collection> pair =  this.createSubReportForHTMLTable(htmlTableString);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("companyLogo", image);
        parameters.put("dynamiJasperReport", pair.getLeft() );
        parameters.put("dynamiJasperReportData",  pair.getRight());
        parameters.put("anotherSubreportDataSource", anotherSubreportDataSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReportFilePath, parameters,
                    new JREmptyDataSource());
            System.out.println("Report filling time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

            if ("PDF".equals(request.getExportType())) {
                reportService.exportToPdf(jasperPrint, response, "MainReport.pdf");
            } 

Here compiledReportFilePath = "C:\Report\mainReport.jasper
Here is how I'm creating dynamic Jasper Report
    public Pair<JasperReport, Collection> createSubReportForHTMLTable(String htmlTable) throws Exception {
        if (htmlTable == null || htmlTable.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlTable);
            Elements tables = doc.select("table");
            if (tables == null || tables.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            // Get first table ignore others
            Element table = tables.get(0);
            //Get all rows
            Elements rows = table.select("tr");
            ArrayList<String> columnName = new ArrayList<>();
            Elements headerRow = rows.get(0).select("th, td");

            for (Element header : headerRow) {
                columnName.add(header.text().replace("\"", "'") + "aa");
            }

            DynamicReportBuilder reportBuilder = new DynamicReportBuilder();

            Style rowStyle = new Style();
            rowStyle.setBorderTop(Border.THIN());
            rowStyle.setBorderBottom(Border.THIN());
            rowStyle.setBorderLeft(Border.THIN());
            rowStyle.setBorderRight(Border.THIN());

            for (String column : columnName) {
                AbstractColumn columnBuilder = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                        .setColumnProperty(column, String.class.getName())
                        .setTitle(column)
                        .setWidth(100)
                        .setStyle(rowStyle)
                        .setHeaderStyle(rowStyle)
                        .build();
                reportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilder);
            }

            DynamicReport dynamicReport = reportBuilder.build();

            List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
                Elements columns = rows.get(i).select("td");
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < columns.size(); j++) {
                    data.put(columnName.get(j), columns.get(j).text().replace("\"", "'") + "aa");
                }
                dataList.add(data);
            }

            Collection collection = new ArrayList<>(dataList);

            JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);
            JasperReport jasperReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), new HashMap<>());

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<>(), dataSource);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
            return new Pair<>(jasperReport, collection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


you are close. As with every subreport, you need to tell the main report how the datasource to the subreport will be provided.
Also remember that dynamicJasper uses a custom scripplet class (DJDefaultScriptlet) needed for the dynamic report to properly put some variables in place.
You might look into dynamicjasper sub-reporting examples, which can give you hints on which parts might be missing.
Also, DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(...) method can give you hints on how to wire report and subreports.
Besides the above, you can use DJ with "templates", where depending on your use case, you might manage to put the "non dyamic" info in some templates bands.
Or, you can use the "concatenated report technique", where the 1st report is your main report, and then you concatenate the DJ report, somehow mimicking the sub-report output.

I've already tried sending datasource for subreport through parameter. You can check my updated code. I'm getting this error: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{dynamiJasperReport}. I have also tried to pass JasperPrint type data for $P{dynamiJasperReport}. But nothing worked for me.
As far as I know "concatenated report technique" requires jrxml file path. But I'm using compiled file path means Jasper source file(not jrxml) and also my main report XML code can hold compiled report as a subreport.
Could you please tell me what exactly I'm missing?


Have you tried declaring this parameter as of type "JasperReport" ?
Could you provide more info related to the error shown, since  Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{dynamiJasperReport} could mean a lot of things such as "class cast exception" or alike

Thanks @dj-mamana. You just saved my life.
I’m facing another problem. When a column’s value exceeds a page, the rest prints on a new page. But, the other column’s value, which didn’t overflow, also prints on the new page. Like this
I tried using a setPrintWhenDetailOverflows, but the border of the other column didn’t print. Like this
I want to print only the overflow on new pages and the non-overflow column with a blank value. Like this
How can I do this?

Hi @Dj Mamana, I’ve encountered a new problem. I have a table where the values in some cells are formatted differently(like this). For example, some cells have bold text, some have italic text, and some have both bold and italic text. Additionally, some cells have more complex formatting, such as part of the value being red, another part being blue and bold, and some parts being normal text. How can I apply these different text formats to individual cells (not just entire columns) in the table?
